# logrotate.d установка правила по времени или по размеру

Tags: linux, centos, логирование

Есть задача, сделать ротацию (к примеру раз в неделю) или когда размер лога достигает 50мб

Немного перегуглив, не нашел оптимального решения, ротация дергается кроном раз в Х времени.

Comment: Сейчас есть следующее - по размеру файла : 

{{link}}/file.log { 
  size 50M
  rotate 100 
  dateext 
  dateformat -%Y-%m-%d-%s
... 
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел решение..

Конкретно моя задача делается с помощью maxsize

пример

```
... 
maxsize 20M 
weekly 
...
```

Что собственно и выполнит - если размер файла больше чем 20 МБ - делается ротация или если прошла неделя